# TreeView - Add nodes dynamically via client

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, treeview, telerik, telerik-mvc

I'm just starting to use the Telerik asp.net mvc and I'm stuck on trying to add a node to the tree view via javascript... but I don't see anything in the documentation where this is possible. Anyone done this or maybe can point in the right direction where to find docs or examples?

Here is the code I used to setup the treeview:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Listings", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmListings", name = "frmListings" }))
    { 
        @(Html.Telerik().TreeView()
        .Name("topics")
        .ClientEvents(e => e.OnSelect("onSelect"))
        .BindTo(Model.Topics, mappings => mappings.For<Topic>(binding => binding
                                                .ItemDataBound((item, category) =>
                                                                {
                                                                    item.Text = category.Name;
                                                                    item.Value = category.URI + "|" + category.Id.ToString();
                                                                    item.Selected = (Model.CurrentCategory.Id == category.Id);
                                                                    //item.Expanded = item.Selected;
                                                                })
                                                .Children(category => category.Children)
                                              ))
        )

    }
```

Comment: What kind of binding are you using for the TreeView?

Comment: I believe it's server or non-ajax version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, as of Q3 2011 SP1, there is no client-side API for adding or removing nodes from the TreeView. This has however been logged in Telerik's Public Issue Tracking System (PITS) [right here](http://www.telerik.com/support/pits.aspx#/public/aspnet-mvc/2293). If you want to see this feature in an upcoming release voting adding a commenting on the issue helps greatly.

In the meantime, if this is just for the visual of adding nodes, you can take a look at the HTML generated by the TreeView and add your own elements by doing some HTML manipulation utilizing JavaScript. The TreeView at its core is just a `<ul>` element with individual `<li>` elements representing the nodes, so you could go ahead and add your own `<li>` elements. This will not be reflected in the TreeView's data however.

Comment: Figured this was going to be the case.  Just thought someone may have an example.  In any case- maybe I could use jquery, then once the node is added use an ajax query to  repopulate the TreeView and then expand the new node added...